# Gnome - App keyboard shortcuts don't change when changing layout

Tags: gnome

I latest gnome when I change layout of between dvorak vs plain english, keyboard shortcuts dan't change, they remain mapped to the old layout.

How can I force them to change also without restarting the session?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a work around for this,

Change the order of the input sources in 'region and language' and lock the screen, when you unlock the shortcuts will be for the input source on the top.

A bit silly I know, but it will do until this gets a proper fix.